# Getting 404 Not Found, when hitting localhost flutter web url inside the chrome

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I ran a flutter project using the command
`flutter run -d web-server --web-port=5000`

Here are the output logs for the same, which looks good to me:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on Web Server in debug mode... Syncing files to device Web Server...                                    22,524ms (!)                                        lib/main.dart is being served at http://localhost:5000

Warning: Flutter's support for web development is not stable yet and hasn't been thoroughly tested in production environments. For more information see https://flutter.dev/web

  To hot restart changes while running, press "r". To hot restart (and refresh the browser), press "R". For a more detailed help message, press "h". To quit, press "q".
```

But when I am opening the url http://localhost:5000 in the browser, it is throwing error 404 not found.

Comment: try `http://localhost:5000/#/`

Answer (score 4):

The issue was resolved after running the following command
`flutter config --enable-web`.
I found the above solution from this [link](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web)

When I created the project, web module was already there and I assumed web config is already enabled. Hence, I didn't run the above command. After doing some research and doing few trials and errors, I ran the above command and it worked.